# How can I download the image files from mdn web docs learning area assignments on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have provided the link to the desired files to be downloaded below:

https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/tree/main/html/multimedia-and-embedding/mdn-splash-page-start/originals

I try to click on download raw file but it does nothing.